# Working in GCP free tier rather than free trial, or suspending the free trial

Tags: google-cloud-platform, web-services

I believe I've made a mistake today.  I wanted to start doing some things with the Google Cloud Platform free tier, without starting the clock on their offer of a $300 credit for three months.

I went through a signup that I thought was for accessing the free tier, but now I see I am active in the free trial, with my 90-day countdown running when I'm not really ready for that to happen.

1. Is there a way to suspend the free trial, so I'm not using its services and my 90-day countdown stops?
2. Alternatively, if I figure out a way to simply delete my GCP free-trial account, would I be able to re-join the free trial later and still have most or all of the 90 days available then?
3. I take note of the GCP documentation saying that materials created under the free trial are deleted at the end of the 90 days if I don't upgrade.  Therefore, I ask:  if I can't suspend the free trial, is there a way to choose to put my work in the free tier even when I'm active in the free trial, so that it won't be deleted?
4. If I can't salvage the time remaining on my existing GCP free trial, what happens if I try to sign up later using one of my other Google accounts?  I'm referring to accounts I created simply for the sake of having additional Gmail addresses, so all the accounts are connected at least to the degree of the main account retrieving email from the others.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answers at your questions but I think that you can re-join the trial only by using a new account and a different credit card.

I'm sure that you can post all you questions directly to GCP billing support that is always free. Just enter in your project, click on the question mark on the top right of the interface and the click on "get support". On the new page you'll be able to choose if you'd like to receive phone or chat support.

Cheers

Matteo

Answer (score 0):

I think you need either a different address/name or a different credit card. There are a TON of people out there who how dont have credict cards. My recent anecdote: My free credit ran out waaaay before I had any idea what I was doing with it, So, I asked my mom if I sould sign her up for it and use her account. We live at the dame address and the credict card which i used t sing up is linked to her account.
There doesnt seem too much hard in trying , but just dont rip through your credicts super fast in case they want to to pay them back.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1135314)